# Conditional inclusion of files based on an Environment variable in a WIX file

Tags: wix

So I have a deployment project based on WIX.  I notice that you can include features and files  in there.  However I only want to deploy a particular file if the DEV/QA environment is selected.  If they select Production I want it to ignore this particular file.

Is there a way in the .wxi file to conditionally include a feature / directory & files based on a particular value of a variable?

ie. I want to have something like the below - potentially the componentRef included dynamically?  (I have sanitised the values).

```
<Feature Id="MyApplication" Title="MyApp" Description="My Application" ConfigurableDirectory="MYAPP" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="AppEmailTemplatesDir" />
 </Feature>
```

and then further down

```
<Directory Id="EmailTemplatesDir" Name="EmailTemplates">
    <Component Id="AppEmailTemplatesDir" Guid="{A-GUID}">
         <File Id="EmailTemplate1.htm" Name="EmailTemplate1.htm" DiskId="1" Source="..\..\EmailTemplates\EmailTemplate1.htm" />
    </Component>
</Directory>
```

Any ideas? We do have custom Actions code (VB.NET) but I'm not sure how that could be used apart from writing code to include files.

Comment: Do you need to conditionally include the files in the output package? Or, include ALL the files, but then conditionally install some of those? The answer depends on this

Comment: When I install - if the user selects QA or DEV as the environment I want to include the files in the installation.  If they select PRODUCTION then I don't want to include the files (ie. I don't want to overwrite any files that are currently there on production). So I'm not trying to exclude individual files - I either want all the files or I don't want any based on the environment.  Hope that helps clarify :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can use a Component NeverOverwriteOption="yes" option to ensure the installer doesn't overwrite the files when they exists.

Unless the environment conditional stuff was easy to figure out - this seems to achieve what I need which is to not overwrite the file on production.

I also found that on uninstall it was deleting all the folders (as expected) but to keep the template path I could use the Permanent="yes" attribute.

After discussion we've decided to keep all the files in source control and deploy them.  But at least I learnt about NeverOverwriteOption and Permanent :)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a variety of ways to do this ... this is what worked for me in Visual Studio 2013.

1. In the WiX project **Properties / Tool Settings** add this to **Additional parameters / Compiler:**:

   ```
   -dReleaseType=$(ReleaseType)
   ```
2. Create a component group containing only the additional file (this is left as an exercise for the reader)
3. In the main `.wxs` file add something like this where `PDBFile` is the id of the component group in step 2:

   ```
   <!-- Installs a PDB file for daily builds -->
   <?if $(var.ReleaseType) = daily ?>
     <ComponentGroupRef Id="PDBFile"/>
   <?endif?>
   ```
4. Run `devenv` to build the WiX project with `ReleaseType` set in the environment